# Accessing uninitialized object. How is this possible?

Tags: c++

I am declaring a pointer, I do not initialize it, but when I call the method it works normal, in that case it should not give segment fault for accessing an uninitialized object?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass() {
        std::cout << "CONSTRUCTORr\n";
    }

    void myMethod() {
        std::cout << "METHOD\n";
    }


};

int main() {
  MyClass* myClass = nullptr;
  myClass->myMethod();
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the code above is 0, and prints the text "METHOD"

Comment: You're in UB land. Anything can happen. If you want the reason why this is likely behaviour you are observing: The compiler figured out that `myMethod()` doesn't depend on `this` and likely inlined it completely.

Comment: undefined behaviour doesn't mean your code wont appear to work correctly

Comment: The compiler *can* (not guaranteed) convert a non-virtual member function call to a straight function call, so the pointer isn't even evaluated at all.  You've invoked undefined behavior, but since it's undefined working normally is allowed.

Comment: @MarkRansom Any non-virtual call is a "straight" function call. The only difference is that `this` is passed as first argument but that doesn't mean that `this` must be dereferenced. It's perfectly fine to pass a zero `ECX` if `ECX` is never used

Comment: @SebastianHoffman It's perfectly fine for the compiler to emit that code, but it doesn't have to. It's also allowed to emit code that crashes, AFAIK.

Comment: @user253751 thats true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am declaring a pointer, I do not initialize it
>
> ```
> MyClass* myClass = nullptr;
> ```

Actually, you did initialise the pointer. It points to null.

> when I call the method it works normal, in that case it should not give segment fault for accessing an uninitialized object?

No. There is no guarantee that calling member function through null would "give segment fault" (note that there is also no guarantee that it wouldn't "give segment fault").

The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> The output of the code above is 0, and prints the text "METHOD"

This is one potential behaviour. All other behaviours are possible as well because no behaviour is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is technically UB, you get away with it because `myMethod` never dereferences `this`.  Try it with a method that (say) accesses a member variable and you will get a very different result.